# Join (very) separated git commits

Tags: git, rebase

I want to join two commits, very separated commits. I'm going to make a pull request so I need that an old commit and a new one are joined.

Things are more or less like this in my branch:

- new commit
- about 43 commits of several people
- my old commit
- rest of the commits

I've been reading the interactive rebase doc. I think it would be something like `git rebase --interactive HEAD~43`, but I'm not sure... Is there a way to select the SHA1 of each commit and join them?

Answer (score 1):

easiest way imo would be to proceed like this:

```
git checkout <old-commit-hash>
git checkout -b new-branch
git cherry-pick <new-commit-hash>
```

This should create a branch where you have:

- new commit
- old commit
- rest of the commist

Comment: Thanks Emil, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Finally I had to make a new branch and import changes manually because the cherry-pick failed for a conflict. I'm not sure this was the better solution.  when I made 2nd step I, the new branch I realize that all commits above mine (old) commit had disapered. Anyway, thank you very much for you time. Daniel.

Comment: I'm still wondering how to solve this issue with a git rebase, anyone? Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: Using `git rebase -i HEAD~43` should open an editor with all the 43 commits, each line should look like `pick 0deadbeef <Commit message>`, you can change pick to drop on all commits except the ones you want.. Most likely you'll still run into the conflict however, since the new commit seem to be dependent on one of the intermittent commits.